# C++ object oriented problems

Tags: c++, object

This is an assignment i am trying to figure out:

> Create a new project named Project3 and create a class named Rover
>
> Within the Rover class, specify the following member instance variables:
>
> - name(string)
> - x position on a grid (integer)
> - y position on a grid (integer)
> - direction by compass – N, S, E, or W (String)
> - speed (0 – 5 meters per second, integer)
>
> Within the Rover class, specify the following methods:
>
> - Default constructor – set the rover’s position to (0,0), its speed to 0, its direction to
>     North.
> - Constructor that receives parameters to initialize all five instance variables described above
> - Setter methods for each instance variable
> - Getter methods for each instance variable
> - getRoverData – returns a string that displays values for each instance variable of the
>     current rover object, placing each value on a separate line, as follows:
>
>   ```
>   Rover name: A
>   X-position: 0
>   Y-position: 0
>   Direction: E
>   Speed: 1
>   ```
>
> Create a class client (main) that creates an array of the a maximum of five rovers and gets the initial
>   values for all rovers from the user. After the user specifies values for each rover, display a summary
>   of the rover’s values as shown above.

**I have about a billion errors and i dont know why.**

```
using namespace std;

class Rover {
private:
    string name;
    int x;
    int y;
    string direction;
    int speed;
    int position[10][10];
public:
    void Rover();
    void constructor(string name, int x, int y, string direction, int speed);
    void setName(string name);
    void setX(int x);
    void setY(int y);
    void setDirection(string direction);
    void setSpeed();
    string getName();
    int getX();
    int getY();
    string getDirection();
    int getSpeed();
    string getRoverData();



};

void Rover::Rover() {
    r1.position[0][0];
    r1.speed = 0;
    r1.direction = "N";
}

string Rover::getRoverData() {
    cout << "Rover name: " << r1.getName() << endl;
    cout << "X-position: " << r1.getX() << endl;
    cout << "Y-position: " << r1.getY() << endl;
    cout << "Direction: " << r1.getDirection() << endl;
    cout << "Speed: " << r1.getSpeed() << endl;
}

void Rover::constructor(string name1, int x1, int y1, string direction1, int speed1) {
    r1.name = name1;
    r1.x = x1;
    r1.y = y1;
    r1.direction = direction1;
    r1.speed = speed1;

}

void Rover::setName(string name) {
    r1.name = name;
}

void Rover::setX(int x) {
    r1.x = x;
}

void Rover::setY(int y) {
    r1.y = y;
}

void Rover::setDirection(string direction) {
    r1.direction = direction;
}

void Rover::setSpeed(int speed) {
    r1.speed = speed;
}

string Rover::getName() {
    return name;
}

int Rover::getX() {
    return x;
}

int Rover::getY() {
    return y;
}

string Rover::getDirection() {
    return direction;
}

int Rover::getSpeed() {
    return speed;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string name;
    int x;
    int y;
    string direction;
    int speed;

    Rover r1;
    r1.constructor("Yoda", 3, 3, "N", 3);

    cout << "Enter name for Rover: ";
    cin >> name;
    r1.setName(name);
    cout << "Enter its x position: ";
    cin >> x;
    r1.setX(x);
    cout << "Enter its y position: ";
    cin >> y;
    r1.setY(y);
    cout << "Enter direction N,E,S,W: ";
    cin >> direction;
    r1.setDirection(direction);
    cout << "Enter its speed: ";
    cin >> speed;
    r1.setSpeed(speed);

    r1.getRoverData();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _" I have about a billion errors"_ - and yet you couldn't be bothered to post even _one_ of them. Please include the exact error messages you are getting _in_ your post.

Comment: is this a class or a header file  it appears that you have fused them into one!

Comment: There are a lot of basic errors in this code. If you're not sure about what you're doing, you should write fewer lines of new code before attempting compilation. That way, you will have fewer errors in a more localised area.

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian It's a complete program in one file, and it happens to contains a class. This is a perfectly legitimate way to write small sample programs, and sometimes it's required by university judging programs to have the source in one file.

Comment: ... though there are lots of missing includes and also the dreaded `using namespace`.

Comment: @cdhowie well then I learned something!

Comment: @FeatheredOrcian Keep in mind what `#include` does: it literally pretends that the contents of that file were dumped at the site of the `#include`!

Comment: @cdhowie Java was my first language with c++ being thy second; it's always better to learn basic concepts later than to never learn said basic concepts.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your example appears incomplete. I'm guessing you just missed including the following lines in your post

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
```

First, constructors do not have a return type so `void Rover();` makes no sense. Remove `void` and you're golden there.

Second, what exactly do you think `r1` is supposed to be? The compiler should tell you the identifier is undefined because it isn't. remove `r1.` from your member functions (i.e. anything function starting with `Rover::`. and you're golden there.

Third, what do you think `r1.position[0][0]` is going to do? It's just an expression that does nothing. Even `position[0][0]` is not going to do anything. Perhaps you want to initialize the array somehow but you haven't provided enough information to determine what you're trying to accomplish with it.

Fourth, the member function `void Rover::setSpeed(int)` has not been declared within the `Rover` class. Did you forget something? Based on your code it should be

```
int Rover::getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}
```

Fifth, `void Rover::setSpeed();` doesn't make much sense unless it actually accepts an argument.